# Magento 2 - Construct a HTTP Post REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I construct a REST api using POST as follow

etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/module-webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/BonusPoint/updateFreeBonusPoint" method="POST">
        <service class="Vendor\BonusPoint\Api\BonusPointInterface" method="updateFreeBonusPoint"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Vendor\BonusPoint\Api\BonusPointInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\BonusPoint\Api;

interface BonusPointInterface {

    /**
     * Update free bonus point of a customer.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $customerId Customer ID.
     * @param int $point Free bonus point balance.
     * @return boolean True if success. Otherwise, false.
     */
    public function updateFreeBonusPoint($customerId, $point);
}
```

Vendor\BonusPoint\Model\BonusPoint.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\BonusPoint\Model;

use Vendor\BonusPoint\Api\BonusPointInterface;

class BonusPoint implements BonusPointInterface {

    protected $_customerBonusPointFactory;

    public function __construct(\Vendor\BonusPoint\Model\CustomerBonusPointFactory $customerBonusPointFactory) {
        $this->_customerBonusPointFactory = $customerBonusPointFactory;
    }

    public function updateFreeBonusPoint($customerId, $point) {
        try {
            $customerBonusPoint = $this->_customerBonusPointFactory->create();
            $customerBonusPoint->load($customerId);
            $customerBonusPoint->setFreeBonusPoint($point);
            $customerBonusPoint->save();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

When I run curl to test:

```
curl -X POST "http://local.magento/index.php/rest/V1/BonusPoint/updateFreeBonusPoint" \
     -d "customerId=1&point=123" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer soqsupye97th0sd0le136u3l933vto1o"
```

It returns:

```
{
    "message": "Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "trace": null
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento do not  support urlencoded requests.

Please specify content type:
Add -H "Content-type: application/json" to curl command  and send body as  {"customerId": 1, "point":1 23}

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue implementing a payment gateway. You need to define a way for Magento to deserialize url-encoded requests.
Take a look to this repository. In more specific how Deserializer and Decoder works.

repo : https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2

What you need :

https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2/tree/master/Model/PostbackNotification
https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2/tree/master/Webapi/Rest/Request/Deserializer
https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2/blob/master/etc/di.xml

Similar issue : [Magento 2 API: 3rd Party makes a post request to magento API with x-www-form-encoded data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281522/magento-2-api-3rd-party-makes-a-post-request-to-magento-api-with-x-www-form-enc/302593#302593)

Answer (score 0):

Magento REST API expects only json encoded data (not url encoded data). Here is an example, show proper encoding of data and header.

```
<?php

$jsonEncodedData = json_encode(array('username'=>'user', 'password' => 'password'));

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://magento.local/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonEncodedData,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```