# Magento 2 - Really need help "Server can´t understand Content-Type HTTP header..."

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I´m a newbie with Magento 2 and the REST API so I need a little help with this code because I tried many things and the result is always the same.

```
$adminUrl='http://mylink.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "user", "password" => "password");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token= json_decode($token);

$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token");

$requestUrl='http://mylink.com/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/products';

$ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$post ='{
            "product": {
                            "sku": "0010001234",
                            "name": "PRODUCTO DE PRUEBA",
                            "attributeSetId": "4",
                            "price": 20,
                            "status": 1,
                            "visibility": 4,
                            "typeId": "virtual",
                            "weight": 0,
                            "extensionAttributes":  {
                                "stockItem":    
                                    {
                                        "stockId": 1,
                                        "qty": 20,
                                        "isInStock": true,
                                        "isQtyDecimal": false,
                                        "useConfigMinQty": true,
                                        "minQty": 0,
                                        "useConfigMinSaleQty": 0,
                                        "minSaleQty": 0,
                                        "useConfigMaxSaleQty": true,
                                        "maxSaleQty": 0,
                                        "useConfigBackorders": false,
                                        "backorders": 0,
                                        "useConfigNotifyStockQty": true,
                                        "notifyStockQty": 20,
                                        "useConfigQtyIncrements": false,
                                        "qtyIncrements": 0,
                                        "useConfigEnableQtyInc": false,
                                        "enableQtyIncrements": false,
                                        "useConfigManageStock": true,
                                        "manageStock": true,
                                        "lowStockDate": "string",
                                        "isDecimalDivided": true,
                                        "stockStatusChangedAuto": 0,
                                        "extensionAttributes": {}
                                    }
                                },
                            "options": [],
                            "tierPrices": [],
                            "customAttributes": []
                        },
                        "saveOptions": true
        }';

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)",
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$post
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);
print_r($result);
return $result;
```

after run this I recieved the following message:

```
stdClass Object ( [message] => Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded )
```

honestly I have many days trying to resolve this issue but not luck until now. So that is why I am asking for help now.

So thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/132149/20064

Answer (score 1):

Well, after I found the application POSTMAN I could fix my problem and now the code is working. Here is how it must to be.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://mylink.com/index.php/rest/V1/products",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n\t\"product\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"sku\": \"0010001234\",\n\t\t\t\t\"name\": \"producto de prueba\",\n\t\t\t\t\"attributeSetId\": \"4\",\n                        \"price\": 20,\n                        \"status\": 1,\n                        \"visibility\": 4,\n                        \"typeId\": \"virtual\",\n                        \"weight\": 0,\n                        \"extensionAttributes\":  {\n                            \"stockItem\":    \n                                {\n                                    \"stockId\": 1,\n                                    \"qty\": 20,\n                                    \"isInStock\": true,\n                                    \"isQtyDecimal\": false,\n                                    \"useConfigMinQty\": true,\n                                    \"minQty\": 0,\n                                    \"useConfigMinSaleQty\": 0,\n                                    \"minSaleQty\": 0,\n                                    \"useConfigMaxSaleQty\": true,\n                                    \"maxSaleQty\": 0,\n                                    \"useConfigBackorders\": false,\n                                    \"backorders\": 0,\n                                    \"useConfigNotifyStockQty\": true,\n                                    \"notifyStockQty\": 20,\n                                    \"useConfigQtyIncrements\": false,\n                                    \"qtyIncrements\": 0,\n                                    \"useConfigEnableQtyInc\": false,\n                                    \"enableQtyIncrements\": false,\n                                    \"useConfigManageStock\": true,\n                                    \"manageStock\": true,\n                                    \"lowStockDate\": \"string\",\n                                    \"isDecimalDivided\": true,\n                                    \"stockStatusChangedAuto\": 0,\n                                    \"extensionAttributes\": {}\n                                }\n                            },\n                        \"options\": [],\n                        \"tierPrices\": [],\n                        \"customAttributes\": []\n                },\n                \"saveOptions\": true\n}\n\n\t",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Postman-Token: token",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible)"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```