# Magento 2 API: 3rd Party makes a post request to magento API with x-www-form-encoded data

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, third-party-module

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway with my headless magento 2 website.

So after the payment is processed/failed, the payment website makes a POST request to my API with x-www-form-encoded data, and it throws me the following error:

> {"message":"Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded","trace":null}

I've tried using:

```
   $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $data = json_decode($request_body,true);
```

But this doesn't work either.

Normal form works, sending these params as JSON works too, but they are sending the params in x-www-form-encoded format, and we can't change that.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the same issue. You need to define a way for Magento to deserialize url-encoded requests.
Take a look to this repository. In more specific how Deserializer and Decoder works.

repo : https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2

What you need :

https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2/tree/master/Model/PostbackNotification
https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2/tree/master/Webapi/Rest/Request/Deserializer
https://github.com/ICEPAY/Magento-2/blob/master/etc/di.xml